# How can I unlock new components?

Tags: factory-idle

I'm playing factory idle, and I wonder when I'll open the next components. I can hardly earn money with this components.

When/how do I unlock new components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Achievement]

On the achievements list, you can see that you'll unlock researches (which allow you to research new components) when your average income gets over $1.4.